# How to hide checkboxes that aren't checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to hide checkboxes that aren't checked? I have three checkboxes and I'm looking for a way to hide the ones that aren't checked. The code I have now hides all checkboxes and I'm trying to hide the ones that aren't checked.

This is my code:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function ()
        {
            //Check if the box is checked
            var x = $(this).is(':checked');
                      
            //if checkbox is NOT checked
            if(x === false) 
                {
                    //Hide the choice
                    $(this).parent().hide();
                }

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="B">A</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="I">B</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="A">C</label><br />
```

Comment: no checkboxes are showing because your code is all done, to make it functional, use the `change` event to check if it's checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@5alidshammout is right. You need a change event and if you want to show all again on uncheck of that box you can simply use if statement. Also starting tags for `<label>` were missing in your code too.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
      //Check if the box is checked
      var x = $(this).is(':checked');

      //if checkbox is NOT checked
      if(x === false) {
        //Hide the choice
        $(this).parent().hide();
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').parent().show();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="B">A</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="I">B</label><br />
<label><input type="checkbox" name="testing" value="A">C</label><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a checkbox is checked or not with this:

```
if (document.getElementById('testing').checked) {
//something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
 // Hide the choice
 $(this).hide();
```

Instead of,

```
// Hide the choice
$(this).parent().hide();
```